# Where to find the model identifier in Form Recognizer?

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I have trained a custom form identifier using Form Recognizer Studio:

[image]

The model is trained and it seems to be working well.

Now, I want to use this model using Power Automate, but I need the model identifier, but Where Can I Find It?

[image]

I have searched it everywhere in Azure, but no luck:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Studio you can find the models IDs within the projects in the Model tab. Please note though that the Form Recognizer Power Automate connector does not yet support the new preview release and supports only the 2.1 GA API. In order to use it you need to train the model in the 2.1 release and use https://fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net/. In 2.1 you will also find the model ID in the UX.

If you want to use the new Studio and preview API in power automate you can create a custom connector and call the REST API directly using the AnalyzeDocument API https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/form-recognizer-api-v3-0-preview-1/operations/AnalyzeDocument
In this case you will need to provide the model name which is the unique model name you gave the model when training it.

Comment: thanks for helping! It's indifferent to me which studio I use. I just want to consume the model somehow whenever files are added to a folder or blob. I've tried the old studio, and now I get the model id. However, in Power Automate, I get the error: Analyze request is either invalid or missing required parameters. Refer to the API reference and retry your request. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, at this point with the model ID not available, consider using HTTP in your logic app, instead of Form Recognizer Logic App. Ways to make it better would be to keep the model ID as a variable and have a delay between REQUEST and GET

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).